# Laravel Dusk: How to get HTML from element?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I understand that you can get the text from an element, like this:

```
$text = $browser->text('.selector');
```

My question is: How can you get the raw HTML content? E.g. the following doesn't work

```
$text = $browser->html('.selector');
```

E.g. if the element is:

```
<div class='selector'><p>Hello</p></div>
```

I'd like to get the following as the output (with the < p> tags):

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the source code of your element you should use the `element()` method together with the `getAttribute()` like this:

```
$html = $browser->element('.selector')->getAttribute('innerHTML');
// now in $html you have HTML inside .selector element
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Try these 2 links too which are extremely useful for me [github](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/303#issuecomment-311656596) and [forum](https://www.5balloons.info/understanding-selectors-laravel-dusk-browser-testing)

Answer (score 3):

update laravel 8.75.0 and laravel dusk 6.19

```
$browser->element('yourElement')->getDomProperty('innerHTML');
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a method to get the inner HTML, but you can use [getText()](https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/1.3.0/Facebook/WebDriver/Remote/RemoteWebElement.html#method_getText) to extract inner Text.

```
<div class='selector'><p>Hello</p></div>
```

```
<?php 
  $innerText = $browser->element('.selector p')->getText();
  // $innerText = 'Hello'
?>
```

Tried on laravel/framework 9.0.2; laravel/dusk 6.22.0; php-webdriver/webdriver 1.9.0;